# How to pass arguments to ASTFrontendAction

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, libtooling

Is there a way I can pass constructor arguments to classes inheriting from `clang::ASTFrontendAction` in programs based on libtooling? All examples I have found online look something like this:

```
int main() {
    ClangTool Tool(...);

    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<SomeFrontendAction>().get());
}
```

But what if `SomeFrontendAction` needs to be aware of, i.e. options passed in by the tools user? How can I pass those on to the constructor of `SomeFrontendAction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Instantiating-a-ToolAction-with-constructor-args-td4052470.html) while looking for an answer to this question. You should create your own version of `newFrontEndActionFactory`. The original code for `newFrontEndActionFactory` is:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<FrontendActionFactory> newFrontendActionFactory() {
  class SimpleFrontendActionFactory : public FrontendActionFactory {
   public:
    std::unique_ptr<FrontendAction> create() override {
      return std::make_unique<T>();
    }
  };
 
  return std::unique_ptr<FrontendActionFactory>(
      new SimpleFrontendActionFactory);
}
```

I replaced `T` with `SomeFrontendAction`, added a constructor to class `SimpleFrontendActionFactory` and then pass the options to `SomeFrontendAction`. The resulting function looks something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<FrontendActionFactory> myNewFrontendActionFactory(string options) {
  class SimpleFrontendActionFactory : public FrontendActionFactory {
   public:
    SimpleFrontendActionFactory(string options) : mOptions(options) {}

    std::unique_ptr<FrontendAction> create() override {
      return std::make_unique<SomeFrontendAction>(options);
    }

   private:
    string mOptions;
  };
 
  return std::unique_ptr<FrontendActionFactory>(
      new SimpleFrontendActionFactory(options));
}

int main() {
  ClangTool Tool(...);

  return Tool.run(myNewFrontendActionFactory(options).get());
}
```

Comment: I somehow forgot about this question but this is very helpful, thank you.